# How to test background to foreground on ios with xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, background-foreground

after read some of your comments in other post about background/foreground task, I need to view the returned values when my app comes back from background to foreground. The problem is when I send the app to background (clicking home button on the iphone, or clicking Simulate Background Fetch on XCODE->Debug) the xcode stops the running (including the log). So, I can't continue showing NSLog messages.

I don't know If I explained me well.

Answer (score 1):

> Mine does not stop to debug, it still continues when it goes to background(clicking home button) and comes to foreground when clicked in app icon. I think this should be default setting but if its not happening in yours then try this

Steps

1. Select your project's target
2. Select info tab
3. Under the custom iOS target properties, if you can see the key named "Application does not run in background" then set is value to NO otherwise do Step 4.
4. ADD a key= "Application does not run in background", type= "bolean", value= "NO"
5. Run your project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in debug console.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Check your application settings:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is different. I run the app from play button on XCODE, but later I need to test what happens when my app comes back from background. To test it, I click on home button, it's now when XCODE stops the logger. But thanks for your comment.

Comment: i uploaded a screenshot could you check it